# how to do validation for directives inside form?

Tags: angular, angular-forms

i have a form which uses directives inside my html like

```
 <form  novalidate #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="updateListing(form)" [ngClass]="{'was-validated': isSubmitted}">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h2>Seller Information</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-box">
        <listing-seller [listingSeller]="listingSeller" [listingForm]="form"></listing-seller>

        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">

                <label for="Seller_InsideCityLimits"> Inside city limits</label>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" [value]="true" [(ngModel)]="listingSeller.insideCityLimits" name="InsideCityLimits"> Yes
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" [value]="false" [(ngModel)]="listingSeller.insideCityLimits" name="InsideCityLimits"> No
                </label>
                {{listingEditModel.sellers.insideCityLimits}}
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

component has

```
@ViewChild('form') form: NgForm
```

inside my listing-seller directive i have a field called legalname

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="Seller_SellerLegalName">Seller Legal Name</label>
  <input class="form-control" 
         id="Seller_SellerLegalName" required 
         [(ngModel)]="listingSeller.legalName" 
         name="legalname" 
         type="text" 
         #legalname="ngModel">
</div>
```

and ts file is

```
export class SellerComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input('listingSeller') listingSeller: Location
  @Input('listingForm') listingForm: NgForm

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

i am doing validation using NgForm,
the validation is not happening  inside the directive, how can i do the validtion for the feilds inside the directive?

Comment: It will not work that way since `listing-seller` is not a form input so it is not formally part of ngForm. It would be easier for you to use reactive forms.

Comment: you mean inside listing-seller component validation not working?

Comment: inside Fields not working, form.invalid is always false, even though fields inside are mandatory and not filled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using sub form inside form Use Control container to integrate with parent form directive. Use viewProviders to provide ControlContainer for Existing form

**ControlContainer:**

> ControlContainer is a superclass for form, formcontrol directive.

**applisting.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlContainer, NgControl, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-listing',
  templateUrl: './listing.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./listing.component.css'],
  viewProviders: [ { provide: ControlContainer , useExisting: NgForm} ]
})
export class ListingComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input('value') age:number;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**parent.component.html**

```
<form #f="ngForm" >
  Name
  <input name="fname" type="text" [(ngModel)]="name">
  <app-listing  [value]="age"></app-listing>
</form>
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ys3jyu